# Scatterplot for multiple regression results in R

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression

I am trying to find a way to get a scatterplot in R of actual values vs. regressed values. Example:

```
fit = lm(y ~ a + x + z)
```

I get the results `y ~ 2*a + 3*x - 7*z + 4`

Now how do I make a scatterplot plotting `y` against `2*a + 3*x - 7*z + 4`? As well as creating a trendline.

(And, by the way, I tried the `plot()` function. It didn't seem to have what I need)

Comment: Plots are two-dimensional. With some tricks we can (usually badly) plot three-dimensional data. Your data is four-dimensional. I don't know how you want to plot this.

Comment: No, I want to plot "y" as my y value and (2*a + 3*x - 7*z + 4) as my x value (or vice versa, I'm not sure it really matters). It is a 2-dimensional scatter plot. Sorry if that was unclear in the original question.

Comment: So, you want `plot(y ~ fitted(fit))`?

Comment: I think you should mark this as an answer @Roland

Answer (score 0):

Look at `plot(fit)`, or the help for lm, which you can access using `?lm`.

From your question, it sounds like you want to plot your actual values against the fitted values.  There is a plot method for `lm` which does this out of the box.

You could always build it yourself, say in `ggplot2`, by accessing the fitted values.  Check out your object using `str(fit)` for all of the data that captured during the regression.